# single click makes two ajax call unwantedly and DOM not updated until i refresh my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

my click on span sends an ajax request and delete clicked todo from database. but in the dom it is not removed until i refresh my page.

`my index.html`

```html
<ul class="list">
</ul>
```

in my network tab it sends two xhr requests which i was not mentioned in code.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5gSN.png)

`app.js`

```js
$(".list").on("click","span",function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  deleteTodo($(this).parent());
});
```

```js
function deleteTodo(el) {
  let todoId = el.data("id"), deleteURL = "api/todos/" + todoId;

  $.ajax({
    method: "DELETE",
    url: deleteURL,
  }).then(function(data) {
    el.remove();
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

Comment: Based on the image you posted there was only one AJAX (XHR) request. 302 is a redirect which means the problem is on the server side. The server redirected the request to a page that doesn't exist (404).

Comment: yes. now i understood that the problem was on the server side and fixed it. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: error image]

The above picture shows that the problem was on the server side. In my node backend API's `Router.js` file has a code that redirects it to the `/api/todos` url after deleting a todo. this error caused my `app.js` to reject the promise. so i was not able to update the DOM.

> error causing code

```
router.delete("/:todoId", function(req, res){
    db.Todo.findOneAndDelete(req.params.todoId)
    .then(function(){
        res.redirect("/api/todos");
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        res.send(err);
    })
```

> edited code

```
router.delete("/:todoId", function(req, res){
    db.Todo.findOneAndDelete(req.params.todoId)
    .then(function(){
        res.json({message: 'We deleted it!'});
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        res.send(err);
    })
```

Comment: If you are going to answer your own question you should add more context. What platform/language is this server code in? There is nothing particularly wrong with this answer but without context it isn't clear. I suggest you edit this answer to improve it so that it may help others in the future who hit a similar AJAX issue.

Answer (score -1):

To remove the element after deleting it from the database, get the el parent element, then make the parent remove it

```
function deleteTodo(el) { let todoId = el.data("id"),    deleteURL = "api/todos/" + todoId; $.ajax({ method: "DELETE", url: deleteURL, }).then(function(data) { 
var elparent = $('el parent element')[0];
elparent.removeChild(el); }).catch(function(err) { console.log(err); }); }
```